# Unable to use commas nor semicolons in Chrome/Edge native messaging manifest executable path on Windows

Tags: json, windows, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, chrome-native-messaging

I am building a browser extension for Microsoft Edge and Chrome.

I have the following native manifest file set up:

```json
{
    "name": "io.github.glitterware.passy_cli",
    "description": "Passy CLI",
    "path": "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Passy\\passy_cli\\temp\\bin\\passy_cli\\2023-05-14T14;59;45.321229\\passy_cli_native_messaging.bat",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_extensions": [
        "glitterware.passy_browser_extension@github.io"
    ],
    "allowed_origins": [
        "chrome-extension://lndgiajgfcgocmgdiamhffipffjnpigl/"
    ]
}
```

I have tested that the extension works when the semicolons are replaced with dots.

Is there any way for me to use the path including semicolons?

**EDIT 1**

I have tested a manifest with semicolons on an Ubuntu system and it works properly as expected.

**EDIT 2**

Tried using `^;` and `\;`, no luck so far. Found out that commas don't work either. As a temporary solution I'm using `c` as a replacement character.

Comment: It might be possible if you escape it with a backslash.

Comment: It's a bug in the browser. As a workaround try replacing `;` with `^;`.

Comment: No luck, tried it several times.

Comment: Does it work with Chrome extension?

Comment: Not working with Chrome either, just tested

Comment: Then it should be an issue with chromium, I suggest providing feedback on this site: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list.